# how to hold iphone call using sdk or any private frameworks

Tags: iphone, sdk, call

I recently has this problem ,I want to intercept the iphone call event , and hold a active call, Can this be done? or any sugestion?

Answer (score 2):

You can't.  Sorry.

(and even if it may be possible on a jailbroken device, I doubt you'll find an answer here)